# Sequelize Model.update with include where

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to set the status of Cars model to done based on JobCard Model status

```
        Cars.update({
            status: 'done'
        },
        {
            where: {
                status: 'pending'
            },
        },
        {
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.models.JobCard,
                    where: {
                        id: jobcard_id
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

But in the logs I am seeing this query only

```
 UPDATE "Cars" SET "status"='done',"updatedAt"='2017-10-22 15:57:24.854 +00:00' WHERE "status" = 'pending';
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to find first the Car with the include, then you make the update.

Comment: @Ellebkey
I want to do bulk update

Answer (score 1):

The `include` attribute should be part of the options object (the second parameter passed to the `.update()` method where you have `where` specified), for example:

```
Cars.update({
        status: 'done'
    },
    {
        where: {
            status: 'pending'
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: sequelize.models.JobCard,
                where: {
                    id: jobcard_id
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, Sequelize does not (to my knowledge) support the use of `include` as part of the options parameter passed to the `.update()` method. Each time I've ever tried to do so, even just now (in Sequelize v4.42.0), an error is thrown and the query is not completed successfully.